# How would I prove the following problem on prime numbers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

**Let p be a prime, and suppose that x and y are integers satisfying xy ≡ 0 mod p.
Prove that either x ≡ 0 mod p or y ≡ 0 mod p.**

Is there an identity through which we can do this? I tried to divide to move the x and y around but I could not eliminate them completely.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The initial identity is just saying that prime $p$ divides $xy$. Then [Euclid's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma) or (equivalently) the [Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) (unique prime factorization) immediately gives you that $p$ divides $x$ or $p$  divides $y$ (or both), which can be translated as $x\equiv 0 \bmod p $ or $y\equiv 0 \bmod p$

Answer (score 0):

If $p $ divides neither  $x $ nor $y $, then it can't divide  $xy $, for it would have to be the product of factors of $x $ and $y $, contradicting that it is prime...

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that $xy \equiv 0\bmod p$ but $p$ is not a divisor of either $x$ nor $y$.

Then, by Fermat's Little Theorem

$x^{p-1}\equiv 1\bmod p$ and $y^{p-1}\equiv 1\bmod p \Rightarrow$ $(xy)^{p-1}\equiv 1\bmod p$

But this means that $p$ is not a divisor of $xy$ which is contrary to our assumption.